# Parameterization of inverse gamma prior in Bayesian methods

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, parameterization, inverse-gamma-distribution

For a prior of $\sigma^2 \sim IG(0.01, 0.01)$, often recommended as an uninformative prior for the variance parameter in MCMC approaches and other Bayesian methods, which parameterization does this recommendation correspond to?

Is it shape/scale or shape/rate? That is, in R, would it be `invgamma::dinvgamma(sigma, shape = 0.01, scale = 0.01)` or `invgamma::dinvgamma(sigma, shape = 0.01, rate = 0.01)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: The recommendation for an Inverse Gamma prior on variance parameters uses the shape/scale parameterization. But take care with the `invgamma` package which seems to have mixed up rate and scale.

---

I can see why the parameterization is confusing if you use the [invgamma](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/invgamma/index.html) package: In its [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/invgamma/versions/1.1/topics/invgamma) the Inverse Gamma density is written as

> `f(x) = rate^shape/Gamma(shape) x^(-1-shape) e^(-rate/x)`

In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) on the Inverse Gamma distribution, the pdf is of course the same:
$$ f(x) = \beta^\alpha/\Gamma(\alpha) x^{-\alpha-1}\exp(-\beta/x) $$
but the $\beta$ parameter is described as the scale.

Wikipedia gets it right: $\beta$ is the "scale", not the "rate" of the Inverse Gamma. This is the standard parameterization.

It may be helpful to reason about this by simply plotting the density. Note that I use the `invgamma` package which seems to have mixed up scale and rate.

[image]

The pdf on the right doesn't look like the density of a "noninformative" prior as it puts all its mass on large values of $x$. So if you use the `invgamma` package (better not?), you would specify the "rate"; if you use another implementation, you would specify the scale.

And for more up-to-date prior recommendations, take a look at the Stan documentation: [Prior Choice Recommendations](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations). This guide has five levels of priors, from *flat* to *specific informative*.

For example the recommendations for a weakly informative prior on a scale parameter, such as the variance, include an exponential with expected value 10, a half-normal (0,10) and a half-Cauchy(0,5).

---

```r
library("invgamma")

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
curve(
  dinvgamma(x, shape = 0.01, rate = 0.01),
  main = "shape = 0.01, rate = 0.01",
  from = 0.0001, to = 1.5, n = 10001, font.main = 1,
  xlim = c(0, 1.5), ylab = "f(x)", yaxs = "i"
)
curve(
  dinvgamma(x, shape = 0.01, scale = 0.01),
  main = "shape = 0.01, scale = 0.01",
  from = 0.0001, to = 1.5, n = 10001, font.main = 1,
  xlim = c(0, 1.5), ylab = "f(x)", yaxs = "i"
)
```

Comment: this was incredibly clear and helpful, especially with the code and graphs you have provided. I appreciate it @dipetkov

Answer (score 2):

The inverse gamma is a conjugate prior for $\sigma^2$ in typical Gaussian-data models. The underlying idea is to have a convenient proper-prior approximation to an improper $\sigma^{-2}$ prior, for a weakly informative/low information prior. In the limit as $\epsilon=\beta=\alpha$ goes to $0$, the $\text{inverse gamma}(\epsilon, \epsilon)$ distribution goes to that improper prior. This occurs when $\beta$ is a *scale* parameter, not a rate parameter.

This use goes back at least to about 1993 give or take, that was when I first encountered it - I believe in conversation - and indeed subsequently used it in an illustrative example. Gelman [1] credits Spiegelhalter et al (1994), so that's possibly its first appearance, though I would not be in the least surprised to discover it's a good deal older than that.

A warning: according to Gelman ([1], again) the $\text{inverse gamma}(\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for small $\epsilon$ (where 0.01 or 0.001 are typical choices of small) distribution is not as weakly informative a prior as was hoped for; he says that the results depend on which $\epsilon$ is chosen.

[1]: Gelman, A., (2006),
"Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models,"
*Bayesian Analysis* **1**, No. 3, pp. 515–533
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/taumain.pdf

Comment: I tried taking the limit as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ go to zero and it didn't work. I got zero. Am I mistaken?

Comment: "I did something that I say didn't work but I am not going to show you what I did. Did I make a mistake?" ... I am no mind reader. I have no clue what things you did or where you might have gone wrong. If you want comments on what went wrong, here in comments is not the place for providing the necessary details of your attempt.

Comment: Well... I can't find the claim you made elsewhere. Where better to ask than as reply to your answer? You mention that taking the Inverse Gamma Distribution, setting $\alpha = \beta = \epsilon$ and taking the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$, the distribution's value should approach $1/\sigma^2$. And yet the limit is in fact zero.

Comment: I take it you haven't done any work with improper priors? The limit of the posterior you get is equivalent of using the suggested improper prior (up to the omitted normalizing constant, which of course you can't have with improper priors). Maybe start with a simpler example of improper priors.

Comment: I see. If you compute the posterior the offending gamma function (which caused the prior to go to zero) cancels out, and then you're left with the $1/\sigma^2$. Makes sense. I'd gotten hung up on your wording that it "goes to that prior". I understand now - thanks.

Comment: You can do it more directly without direct reference to the posterior (albeit less formally), but you have to do it the right way; improper priors (which don't have a finite integral) will always "go to 0" in the sense you mean but of course they can't be 0 if they are to integrate to 1. A bit of playing around with flat uniforms and Gaussians with $\sigma\to\infty$ may help illustrate the issues and how one works with them.